# Finding vector equation of two different lines

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was requested to find the vector equation of lines $L_1$, $L_2$, where:

$a.$ $L_1$ passes through the point $(2, 0)$ and is orthogonal to $[1, 3]$

$b.$ $L_2$ passes through $(1, 3)$ and is parallel to $L_3$, where $L_3$ passes through $(-1, 4)$ and $(3, -2)$.

I self study, so without professors to check my answer I can only come here to seek validation/correction. Here is what I attempted.

---

$a.$ Let $\vec{p} = [1, 3]$. Since $L_1 \perp \vec{p}$, $L_1 \parallel \vec{w}$ for any $\vec{w}$ such that $\vec{w} \perp \vec{p}$. Any such $\vec{w}$ will satisfy $\vec{w} \cdot \vec{p} = 0$. Since

$$\begin{align} &\vec{w} \cdot \vec{p} &= 0 \\ &\iff w_1(1) + w_2(3) &=0  \\ &\iff w_1 = -3w_2\end{align}$$

we can let $w_1 = 1 \implies w_2 = -\frac{1}{3}$ to conclude $\vec{v}=[1, -\frac{1}{3}]$ is orthogonal to $\vec{p}$ and therefore parallel to $L_1$. Thus, a vector equation for $L_1$ is given by

$$\vec{g}(t)= \vec{r} + t\vec{v} \tag{with $\vec{r} = [2, 0]$}$$

$b.$ Let $\vec{p_1} = [3, -2], \vec{p_0}= [-1, 4]$. Then $\vec{v} := \vec{p_1} -\vec{p_0} = [4, -6]$ represents the segment of $L_3$ that goes from $(3, -2)$ to $(-1, 4)$. Since $L_3 \parallel L_2$, it follows that $\vec{v} \parallel L_2$. Then a vector equation for $L_2$ is given by

$$\vec{g}(t) = \vec{r} + t\vec{v} \tag{with $\vec{r} = [1, 3]$}$$

---

Besides validation/correction, I would appreciate alternative ways to go about the problem so as to expand my incipient grasp of multivariable calculus. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All that is fine and there isn't a better alternative way.

Comment: Please clarify the [x, y] notation.  Is this merely a vector?
That makes [1, 3] = 1i + 3j = <1, 3> the same thing in three different notations.